# Problemas com tipagem no angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu criei um novo projeto no angular depois de algum tempo e com o projeto limpo eu tentei criar uma variável mas percebi que a tipagem está diferente pois nos meus antigos projetos não dava erro. Não entendo muito bem angular, ainda.
O que eu costumava fazer era: `variavel: string;`

Mas agora, neste novo projeto está dando erro em "variavel".
A tipagem está diferente agora? Não sei o que se passa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que se passa é que nas versões mais recentes do Angular, a checagem de tipos ficou ainda mais estrita.

- https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode
- https://blog.angular.io/angular-cli-strict-mode-c94ba5965f63

O resultado disso é que você precisa ser mais explícito na hora de declarar suas variáveis.

O código abaixo, por exemplo, vai dar erro.

```
export class MyComponent {
  title: string;
}
```

O motivo do erro é que eu estou dizendo que o tipo de `title` é `string`, mas eu não estou inicializando, logo, seu valor é `undefined`.

Para ajeitar isto temos algumas opções:

**Opção 1:** Inicialize-a. É a opção que eu recomendo para a maioria dos casos.

```
title: string = '';

// Ou apenas...
title = '';
```

**Opção 2:** Marque-a como opcional, assim dizemos que ela pode ser `undefined`.

```
title?: string
```

**Opção 3:** Mude o tipo para `string | undefined`, é mais ou menos como a opção anterior, mas mais explícita.

```
title: string | undefined;
```

**Opção 4:** Marque-a com o *Non-null assertion operator*. Com isto estamos garantindo para o compilador que a variável nunca será `null` e nem `undefined`, só que eu só recomendo usar isso em situações específicas porque vc fica responsável por garantir que o valor será sempre válido.

```
title!: string;
```